# Qt is activating window without my consent after using QFileDialog

Tags: qt

Qt 5.12.6 MSVC2017 64-bit on Windows 10, Qt Creator 4.10.1.

I have a top level window derived from `QMainWindow`, which has a `QMdiArea`.

From the first main window I use a file open dialog to open a new document in a `QMdiSubWindow` and place it in the `QMdiArea`.  After the file dialog returns but before I do the logic of opening the document, I have to call `QApplication::setActiveWindow(this)`, to set it back to the main window, because the opening logic depends on the active window.  The need for this somewhat appears related to https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/2950-ActiveWindow-changes-after-closing-QFileDialog in that the `activeWindow` becomes null, regardless of how I parent the file dialog.

I then open a second identical top level window and open another document using the same method.
What's very weird is that after the second `QMdiSubWindow` in the second `QMainWindow` is activated, the *first* `QMainWindow` gets activated again, and thus various follow-on operations affect the document in the first window rather than the second window which is the intended one.  If I click back and forth on the main windows, the activation is correct.

If I create a new document directly from the second `QMainWindow` instead of using the file open dialog, then it works fine.  The new `QMdiSubWindow` is created and shown in the second `QMainWindow`, without the first one getting activated.  So this implicates the file dialog somehow.

When I put a breakpoint on a function triggered by the `QMainWindow::activated` signal, the stack trace shows this signal is coming from within Qt on its own accord, not from someplace in my code directly.

How can I find out why Qt is activating the first window when using the file dialog from the second window?  At this point the code is too large to try to fit a minimal example here on SO.

--EDIT--
I added a one-shot `QTimer` at the end of the function that creates the `QMdiSubWindow`.  Zero milliseconds after in creates the `QMdiSubWindow` it activates the first `QMainWindow`, then activates the current `QMainWindow`.  That workaround seems to work, and the second `QMainWindow` becomes the active one.  But only if I select away from it first.  The fact that the hack works with 0 ms timer is also interesting.  I'll be posting minimal example when I can.
thanks

Comment: Example source code would be really helpful to reproduce the behaviour (may as github gist or a link to a repo)...